# Higher-order functions in MiniZinc

Tags: minizinc

I'm trying to implement [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) in MiniZinc. I'm not sure if it's possible to pass a function directly to another function, so I used an enumeration with a list of function names:

```
enum functions = {add,sub}; 

function var int:sub(var int:a,var int:b) = 
    a-b;

function var int:add(var int:a,var int:b) = 
    a+b;

function var int:higher_order(var functions:func,var int:a,var int:b) = 
    if func==add then 
        add(a,b) 
    elseif func==sub then
        sub(a,b)
    else 
        0
    endif;

var int:a = higher_order(add,3,4);
solve satisfy;
output [show(a)];
```

Alternatively, I can put the function's name and parameters in a [record](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.7.6/en/tuple_and_record_types.html):

```
enum Func = {add,sub};

type func = var record(Func:name, int: x, int: y,int:output1);

function var func:add(int:x,int:y) = (name:add,x:x,y:y,output1:x+y);

function var func:sub(int:x,int:y) = (name:sub,x:x,y:y,output1:x-y);

function var int: eval(func:r) = r.output1;

int: nc = 3;
func: f1 = add(3,4);
var int: nc1 = eval(f1);

solve satisfy;

output [show(nc1)];
```

This method works, though it's not really a higher-order function. Is there any other way to implement higher-order functions in MiniZinc?

Answer (score 1):

Although the use of higher level functions has been proposed for MiniZinc in a paper (https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/MiniZinc-with-Functions-Stuckey-Tack/4f7a420b9ddce7fea682768fa35d2cf436683b28). Support for higher level functions has not yet reached the MiniZinc compiler itself.

Although I cannot provide you with one perfect workaround, often higher order functions can be replaced using normal functions, optional types, or recursive functions